# PhpStorm and JavaScript: I'm getting "Cannot find declaration to go to"

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm

I'm playing with my simple NodeJS project in PhpStorm and suddenly the control-click navigation stopped working. When I click on a required file path, I just get message `Cannot find declaration to go to`. For example:

```
var Controller = require('./lib/Controller');
```

The file is definitely there as the program runs without problems. And if I control-click some global function or object (like "require" itself), the navigation works, the definition of the function/object is opened.

It affects now all my NodeJS/JavaScript projects. Is it possible that I simply disabled some kind of code analysis?

I have recently upgraded from PhpStorm 7 to EAP (to get grunt support) and then to 8.0.1. The problem appeared somewhere during the upgrades. I just can't tell exactly when.

Comment: Have you tried `File | Invalidate caches...` and Restart yet?

Comment: Yes I have. I also tried to create a new project from existing files but nothing helped.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot that shows up the issue? Editor + project view so that your actual directory structure is also shown

Comment: It won't be necessary because I think I have discovered what the problem was. When I was browsing through the settings I noticed that the NodeJS plugin is disabled and marked as "incompatible" with current PHPStorm version. I reinstalled the plugin and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the NodeJS plugin was disabled and in my case marked as "incompatible" with current PhpStorm version. Apparently, NodeJS is necessary for navigation through `require` statements.

It wasn't possible to update the plugin for some reason, so I simply reinstalled it and the problem was fixed.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. 
Check this article **[Answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)**